# How to Call a Smart Contract on the Backend

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node, pallet-contracts

What is the best way to call a contract (based on the Substrate Blokchain) on the backend side from the code? I know there is Polkadot.js but it's rather a frontend focused tool, and there is also cargo-contract which enables us to call a contract from the command line.

In my case I am building a backend, where I will store account with private keys, loaded with the native tokens for gas fees, to call a given contract. Moreover,  I am also looking for a way to sign a message with Polakdot wallet on the frontend, and send this message to backend, to verify the signer. Possibly, the solution should be written in Rust - therefore cargo-contract always comes to my mind, I am just not sure how could I execute the call function straight inside of the code, instead executing it in the command line.

Thanks in advance for any tip

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[polkadot-js/api](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api)** library for both frontend and backend work (*if both frontend and backend are based on Javascript*). 
You can use this api to sign, verify messages and deploy/call ink contracts.

Take a look at the documentation on **[here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api)**.

If you are using any other languages, please find the tool/library that suits you from **[this link](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-tools-index#rpc-and-api-tools)**.

Comment: Thanks! I have even built my entire tool for that during the weekend you can check it out here https://github.com/KowalewskiPawel/Substrate-Polkadot-Smart-Contracts-Caller However the problem is that I am still looking for a Rust oriented tool :)